# Stack Overflow paging not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, pagination, windows-7

I checked that Stack Overflow's `paging` is not working,

I tried to change `paging index` from `1` to `2`, but it is not working.

***To re-produce the issue,***

**Step-1.** Go to see the profile of any user - *For example:* `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1156018/curiousguy`

**Step-2.** Find `View all questions and answers` on page,  → (see in image) - And clicked on `answers` - it will redirect you to this URL - `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1156018/curiousguy?tab=answers`

[image]

**Step-3.** Try to change paging index from `1` to `2` and see the issue - url will be changed like below,

`http://stackoverflow.com/users/1156018/curiousguy?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=2` - but the page is not loaded.

*Please Stack Overflow, fix this issue.*

I am checking the issue in the [Internet Explorer 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11) browser.

Comment: Works for me, I can't repro your issue.

Comment: This appears to be new behavior, that only load the contents with AJAX, then populating the answers container and auto scrolling back to top. Works fine for me. What browser you have? Do you see client errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console, can you just try once in ie browser. if I try to check the same issue second time in same browser it will work but for the first time it is not working.

Comment: @Mat - please try to check in IE browser.

Comment: Add your environment (OS, browser and version) to your question. (And: no thanks.)

Comment: What version of IE? 6? 7? 8? 9? 10? 11? Other? Works fine for me with IE 11.

Comment: I've updated my question, @ShadowWizard - have you tried to check?

Comment: Yes and can't reproduce.

Comment: I have checked the same in 5 different pc and faced the same issue at my work. if it is working fine for you then it's good. thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. IE 11, Chrome, Opera, FF on Windows 8.1.

Comment: now I really wanted to show the demo - but I don't how can I show to you?

Comment: @curiousguy are you sure nothing is loaded? Maybe the contents are loaded, and only the scrolling back to top fails.

Comment: I checked around 5 times the same issue in my IE11 browser, contents are not laoded and scrolling back to top also give me the page 1 result only. Now this is strange, if I click on `3` it works sometimes for page index 3. - when I go to check with your profile `http://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard` it works! :-|